# Issue with populating Bitmap Object in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, bitmap, visual-studio-2015

I'm having issues displaying a Bitmap to a `PictureBox` in **Visual Studio C++**. To simplify things, I just want to create a gradient that is displayed in a `PictureBox`. However, I get these periodic black streaks through the image. I get these even if I set all the byte values to 255. `imageWidth` is 640 and `imageHeight` is 480. In the `tempImage` assignments, I have tried both creating a simple gradient and assigning all pixels to *white (255)*.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    tempImage = new unsigned char *[imageHeight];
    for (int count = 0; count < imageHeight; ++count) {
        tempImage[count] = new unsigned char[imageWidth * 3];
    }
    // populate image
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < imageHeight; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < imageWidth; ++j) {
            tempImage[i][j * 3] = 255; // i * 255 / imageHeight;
            tempImage[i][j * 3 + 1] = 255; // i * 255 / imageHeight;
            tempImage[i][j * 3 + 2] = 255; //  i * 255 / imageHeight;
        }
    }

    Bitmap ^mybm = gcnew Bitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight, imageWidth * sizeof(unsigned char) * 3, Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,(IntPtr) tempImage);

    this->SImage->Image = mybm;
    this->SImage->Show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Bitmap` constructor is expected a single contiguous array of pixel data, however, you are sending it an array of 'unsigned char *' pointers that point to each row of data.

Try allocating your pixel array as one block, you will need to access the rows with a bit of math. Something like:

```
tempImage = new unsigned char [imageHeight * imageWidth * 3];

// populate image
int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < imageHeight; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < imageWidth; ++j) {
        tempImage[i * imageWidth + j * 3] = 255; // i * 255 / imageHeight;
        tempImage[i * imageWidth + j * 3 + 1] = 255; // i * 255 / imageHeight;
        tempImage[i * imageWidth + j * 3 + 2] = 255; //  i * 255 / imageHeight;
    }
}
```

Note: I haven't tried this code, so I don't know if this is the correct order (or even size) for the data.

Comment: This worked (I just had to change the assignment line to `tempImage[i * 3* imageWidth + j * 3] = 255;`

Comment: Also note - the documentation says the third parameter to the `Bitmap` constructor you are using should be a multiple of 4. I don't think you are currently doing that.

Comment: Thanks. My bitmaps will always be either 640x480 or 1024x768.